# phpDesigner 8 how to FTP files to remote server

Tags: php, ftp, ide, text-editor, phpdesigner

I've never had so much difficulty trying to figure out something that should be so simple! I used the FTP Manager to set up a new connection. That's fine, and I see the connection in the FTP/SFTP panel.  But then what?? From my Project Panel, I right click the files > Export To > FTP Folder.   Then I get the FTP Properties window asking for login credentials - every single time.  It just doesn't store the profile from the FTP Manager.  Furthermore, I don't even see where to associate my local directories to the remote one.   ???

I've searched online for over an hour now. Apparently, the built in FTP tool is buggy, but there is little else information.